# Interface Builder: How to load view from nib file

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview

I have a MyCustomView subclassed from *NSView* designed in a .xib.

I would like to insert this view into some of my other xib's round my application. How should I do this? If i drag a custom view and change the class to MyCustomView, but that does not load my xib-file. Can this only be done programmatically or is there a way to do this inside interface builder?

**EDIT1:**

Here is a very small demo-project:
http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=09538344018446482999

It contains the default MainMenu xib and my CustomView xib. I would like my *CustomView.xib* to be displayed inside the custom view added to my *MainMenu.xib* -- using as less code as possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For loading the view you need to add on your window:-
Created custom class of view inheriting to NSViewController

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface NewViewController : NSViewController

@end

#import "NewViewController.h"

@implementation NewViewController

- (instancetype)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

Your xib name is `yourview.xib`

```
- (void)windowDidLoad {
    NSViewController *yourVC = [[NewViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewViewController" bundle:nil];
    [[[self window] contentView] addSubview:[yourVC view]];
}
```

Comment: So I need to programmatically init the view/controller and add it to the custom view in the main view? Afterwards I further need to programmatically add constraints between the two views.

Comment: yes first you need to create custom class inheriting to NSViewController with xib then the same xib you can load in your code as writing above. Also for your reference i have updated the code

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a container view. But I think you will have to use storyboard for it to be doable in interface builder.

Comment: It's not for iOS, so storyboards is not an option?

Comment: Ok sorry, my bad then. Only developed for iOS

Answer (score 0):

Use a view controller as it will handle nib loading for you and provide a place to hook up `IBOutlet` and `IBActions` in a reusable way.

In your app delegate or whatever controller create an instance of your view controller. 
Ask your view controller to load its view. 
Cast the return type to your view class name. 
Then keep a reference to your view controller and possibly the view.

Tell whatever view to add your view as a subview. 
Add any layout constraints. 
( you can build out very generic constraints to add themselves in your view or view controller by overriding  `viewDidMoveToSuperview` or `viewDidMoveToWindow` when `superview` or window are not nil. Use the same to remove your constraints. )

Oddly you remove a view by telling it to remove itself from its `superview`.

Comment: How do you link the view controller to the Xib file?

Comment: There's no real linking. You pass the name of the nib/xib file as a string to initWithNibName:bundle: and always use NSBundle bundleForClass: to pass the bundle. This keeps it reusable and not coupled to the app bundle like NSBundle mainBundle. nil for bundle is same as NSBundle mainBundle. You nib/xib should have file's owner class set to NSViewController or a subclass. Subclass enables IB to recognize custom IBOutlets! but you can always hook things up in code and cast things, and sometimes you should do so.

Answer (score -1):

I'd advise just doing it programmatically:

1. Add a View to your main `xib/storyboard` and set the custom class to your custom view's class
2. In your xib for your custom view, set the File's Owner class to your custom view's class
3. Hook up any `IBOutlets`, etc. as needed
4. Make a __strong property/ivar for holding a reference to the top level `NSView` of the xib
5. Implement `initFromFrame` in your custom view's class roughly as follows:

```
@interface CustomView ()
{
    __strong NSView *nibView;
}
@end

@implementation CustomView

- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        NSArray *nibObjects;
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomView" owner:self topLevelObjects:&nibObjects];
        nibView = nibObjects[1];
        [self addSubview:nibView];
    }
    return self;
}
```

The `IBOutlet` are connected up immediately after the `loadNibNamed` call, so you can do further initialization from there.

Another option is to do things purely programmatically:
1. In your custom `xib`, set the root View's class to your custom class
2. Implement `awakeFromNib` in your custom class to perform initialization
3. Call `loadNibNamed:` on your custom `xib` and programmatically add it to the user interface without interface builder.

Comment: Any explanation as to why you are using `nibObjects[1]` instead of `nibObjects[0]`?

Comment: I just get a Coder error when trying this: fatal error: init(coder:) has not been implemented:

Comment: In my experience working on this sort of thing right now, nibObjects[0] appears to be an application object and not a view. nibObjects[1] contains the view object. The code should find the view by searching the array and not rely on hard-coded numbers always working, so this example is a but flawed.